# Update styling magento 2 in production mode

Tags: magento2, less, deployment

I have a server with a production install of magento.
When I deploy a new version, adding for example a new .less file, the new markup doesn't get loaded. I cleared the cache, rebuild the static-content. Only after switching to developer mode the changes are loaded.

This process, switching back and forth between dev and prod causes a goot 10 minutes downtime.
Can someone explain this? What is the proper way to update css, or anything, for magento 2 in production?

Thank you

Comment: Which command were you using for deploying static-content ?

Comment: bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE nl_BE en_GB en_US fr_FR  -f

Comment: Try `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE nl_BE en_GB en_US fr_FR -f && php bin/magento c:f` If that doesn't work, then also try to call `php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated && php bin/magento setup:di:compile` before it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue as you now and even my above commands do not help. I am facing the issue since I tried to change from `production` mode to `developer` mode. It is a bug.

Comment: Bug Report: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29882

Comment: Can you try to delete your static content with `rm -R pub/static/* generated/*` and generate it again with `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE nl_BE en_GB en_US fr_FR -f && php bin/magento c:f` please?

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in this topic, so I created an [issue in git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29819#issuecomment-685266091).

Also have a look into the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/deployment).

Answer (score 0):

Try to Deploy Content with language code as a parameter

```
PHP bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f EN_Us // change language code as per your requriments
```